# Is Angular .done() animation callback being called twice? (Angular2)

Tags: angular

I've tried a couple of seemingly-common fixes, both shown in the plnkr:

1. specify '`type="button"`' on my button
2. take angular out of dev mode

If you click the 'Next' button, and open the Javascript console, you'll notice my 'done()' function runs twice for each click:

http://embed.plnkr.co/HKlKWfV6JjWRxZiOnAJt/

I also tried passing in the '$event' and using preventDefault() and stopPropagation(), but no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked the code a little to return the expected behavior. Such as moving to the `array` index.

```
done(){
console.log('Running done(). index: ' + this.index);
 //I removed the this.index++ here;
 if(this.index>2) this.index=0;
 this.name=this.strs[this.index];
 this.nameState2='active';

}

next(){
 this.index++; // <=== I removed the comment here.
 //if(this.index>2) this.index=0;
 //this.name=this.strs[this.index];
 this.nameState2='inactive';
}
```

> I moved the `index++` on the `next()` function. But on the console it still calls the `done()` twice. **But the behavior for the name/index is working as it should be.**

Comment: Works for me! Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it helped!